# Nestjs does not use webpack config file when run a build command

Tags: typescript, webpack, nestjs

I have a Node js code which I try to build together with nestjs and webpack.
I try to inject global variables using `webpack.DefinePlugin`, but in the build result I can see the variables not being replaces.

`nest-cli.json` file:

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
    "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
    "sourceRoot": "src",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "webpack": true,
        "webpackConfigPath": "./webpack.config.ts"
    }
}
```

`webpack.config.ts` file:

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import WebpackShellPluginNext from 'webpack-shell-plugin-next';
import isCI from 'is-ci';

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && !isCI;
const cliApiDomain = isDev ? 'localhost' : 'xxx.xxx';
const cliApiUrl = isDev ? 'http://localhost:5000' : 'https://www.xxx.xxx';
const dashboardUrl = isDev ? 'http://localhost:8080' : 'https://xxx.xxxx';

const configuration = (options: webpack.Configuration): webpack.Configuration => ({
    ...options,
    plugins: [
        ...options.plugins!,
        new WebpackShellPluginNext({
            onBuildStart: {
                scripts: ['rimraf dist'],
                blocking: true,
            },
            safe: true,
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            __CLI_API_DOMAIN__: `'${cliApiDomain}'`,
            __CLI_API_URL__: `'${cliApiUrl}'`,
            __DASHBOARD_URL__: `'${dashboardUrl}'`,
        }),
    ],
});

export default configuration;
```

I have `package.json` scripts for running in dev mode and production mode:

```json
.
.
.
        "build": "nest build",
        "build:dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nest build",
.
.
.
```

I use the configured variables in my source code:

```
    private config: IConfig = {
        API_URL: __CLI_API_URL__,
        DASHBOARD_URL: __DASHBOARD_URL__,
    };
```

However, these variables are not replaced with webpack. When I inspect my build code, I can see those variables are still in my code.

I expect to see them replaced.
It seems like Nestjs does not even use my file

After switching file of `webpack.config.ts` to use same logic but with js: `webpack.config.js` it worked. Nestjs won't support TS config file?

---

The issue was. NestJS ignores Webpack files written in TypeScript.

Comment: According to the `NestJS` documentation, in case you use `webpack` compiler, it is encouraged to create `webpack.config.js` file. See https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/monorepo#webpack-options for reference. Alternatively, you could convert your TS file to JS file and build your app as usual: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47180018/5716745

Comment: See the [webpack docs on using TS as a configuration language](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-languages/#typescript)?

Comment: how did you import webpack.config in source code?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by replacing the `webpack` configuration file, with JavaScript one, as NestJS does not support configuration file written with TypeScript.