# Webpack configuration file written in TypeScript not working

Tags: typescript, express, webpack

I'm currently using the following configuration for my project, which is basically an Express API using TypeScript:

- webpack.common.js
- webpack.dev.js
- webpack.prod.js

As explained in the Webpack [docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/), I use a common configuration, which I extend based on the development stage (e.g., dev, prod). When building the app, I use the following npm scripts:

`webpack --config webpack.dev.js` and `webpack --config webpack.prod.js`

The application is built, and everything works just fine. Now I'd like to migrate my configuration files to TypeScript. According to the Webpack [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-languages/), it's possible and there are three possibilities.

- Modify `tsconfig.json`.
- Modify `tsconfig.json` and add settings for `ts-node`.
- Install `tsconfig-paths`.

The first choice is not suitable for me because my `tsconfig.json` is based on [`@tsconfig/node20/tsconfig.json`](https://github.com/tsconfig/bases/blob/main/bases/node20.json), and I don't want to change `module` to `CommonJS`. I'm not quite sure about the third option because there are some [reports](https://github.com/webpack/webpack.js.org/issues/2733) saying that `TS_NODE_PROJECT` is somehow buggy and only works if used along with `cross-env`. So I decided to go for the second choice.

So here is what I did:

- I installed all required dependencies (e.g, `ts-node`, `@types/webpack`, etc.),
- I added `ts_node` config to my `tsconfig.json`. Like so:

```json
  "ts-node": {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "CommonJS"
    }
  }
```

- I update my script in package.json. Like so:

```json
"build:dev": "webpack --config webpack.dev.ts"
```

In the docs, the `npm` command to run the configuration using `TypeScript` and `ts-node` is not mentioned at all. So I'm guessing that I might be able to run the command similarly as I did before. So I did and I got the following output:

[webpack_output_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqMcb.jpg)

Here some extra details:

- I defined `type:module` in my `package.json`. That enforces `ES6` modules.
- If I compile my config files using `ts-node`, I would get similar error unless `--esm` flag is passed in.

So what am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of webpack are you running? Also, is there a reason to want your config file to be Typescript? The project I'm working on is fully Typescript but the config file is .js and I don't really see how making it .ts would improve my project.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Webpack version 5.88.2. We are currently migrating a JS project to TS from scratch. So we'd like to have all codebase in TS.

Comment: You could run `tsc --lib es6 webpack.config.ts` before using the normal webpack command. This will transpile your .ts to .js.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61747984/5064575) also seems very promising.

Answer (score -1):

Since TypeScript would have to be transpiled to JavaScript first, it is not possible to use a .ts file in an npm script command. Write the webpack.dev.ts in JavaScript and rename the file to `webpack.dev.cjs` (common js). This way you can keep the TypeScript config strict and still use a JS file with for example `require()` methods.

You can actually live with this compromise, because the webpack config no longer plays a role after the application is started.

Here you can see an example https://github.com/ztomm/webpack-typescript-boilerplate